# Sent mail to multiple address using Laravel 4 queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 , tying to send mail to multiple user using Queueing Mail , my code looks like -

```
$mailuserlist=DB::table('table')
            ->join('some_table')
            ->select('some_thing')
            ->where('somecondition'))->get();

Mail::queue('mail_template', $data, function($message) use ($mailuserlist)
{
      $message->from('test@desto.co.in', 'Mail Notification');
      foreach ($mailuserlist as $value) {
            $message->to($value['email'],$value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname']);
    }
    $message->subject('Testing mail');
});
```

..it's not at all working . How can i send ail to multiple address ??

Answer (score 6):

It should be possible in two ways as we can see in the source code [framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php):

1. Chaining
2. Using array

**Chaining:**

```
->to($address1, $name1)->to($address2, $name2)->to($address3, $name3)...
```

**Using array of addresses:**

```
->to(array($address1,$address2,$address3,...), array($name1,$name2,$name3,...))
```

Answer (score 4):

[Queueing Mail](http://laravel.com/docs/mail) doesn't seem to support sending 1 mail to multiple user. I think you should queue 1 mail for each of your recipients:

```
$mailuserlist=DB::table('table')
        ->join('some_table')
        ->select('some_thing')
        ->where('somecondition'))->get();

foreach ($mailuserlist as $mailuser) {
    Mail::queue('mail_template', $data, function($message) use ($mailuser) {
        $message
          ->from('test@desto.co.in', 'Mail Notification')
          ->to($mailuser['email'],
            $mailuser['firstname'].' '.$mailuser['lastname'])
          ->subject('Testing mail');
    });
}
```

Comment: Will it hold the controller until all mail sent ?? or it will queue all and release the Controller ??

Comment: I've tried , But not working , giving some error. Do i need to change anything in queue configuration file ??

Comment: The idea of ::queue is to not hold the controller (opposite to ::send)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all emails to send

```
$users = User::select('email')->get()->toArray();
```

And delete the key of array for get an array only with the emails

```
$emails = array_pluck($users, 'email');
```

And then run the Mail::queue

```
Mail::queue('mail.your_view', [], function($message) use ($emails) {
    $message->from('test@from.com', 'Mail Notification');
    $message->to($emails);
    $message->subject('Your Subject');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**

### Sending multiple users

**

```
$users = UsersGroup::where(['groups_id' => $group->id])->get();
    if(!$users->count()) {
        Mail::send('emails.groups.delete-group', [
            'group' => $group->title,
        ], function ($message) use ($group, $users) {

            $message->from(Config::get('mail.from.address'), Config::get('mail.from.name'))
                ->subject(Lang::get('groups.group_deleted'));

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $message = $message->to($user->users->email);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: What about commenting the changes/fixes?